# How would I set each instance of a class to a specific page for a TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to assign each weather location in my app a page in a tab view but am unsure on how to achieve this.

I have a currentPage variable in my location view which should add 1 every time a weather location is shown on screen but instead it just keeps adding one throughout the entire foreach loop I have, so a page number isn't actually assigned to a weather view.

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could assign a page number to each location when iterating through my for each loop.

My location view is shown below. The code I tried is at the bottom in the onAppear modifier in the if statement but it doesn't work like I said above and I am not sure if this is even the right approach for doing something like this. Any help would be great!

```
struct LocationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var weatherVM: WeatherViewViewModel
    @ObservedObject var multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel
    
    @State private var pageSelection = 1
    @State var currentPage: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [Color("BackgroundColorSun"), Color("BackgroundColorSky")], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)).ignoresSafeArea()
        
            if multiLocationVM.weatherVM.count == 0 {
                BlankLocationView(multiLocationVM: multiLocationVM)
            } else {
                TabView(selection: $pageSelection) {
                    ForEach(multiLocationVM.weatherVM, id: \.self.city) { location in
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            VStack(spacing: -10) {
                                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                                    Text("\(location.getWeatherIconFor(icon: location.weatherIcon))")
                                        //.innerShadow(Color(.red))
                                        .font(.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 64))
                                        .innerShadow()
                                        //.foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .offset(x: -70, y: -35)

                                    Text("\(location.getTempFor(temp: location.weather.current.temp))°")
                                        .font(.system(size: 96, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                                        .tracking(-0.41)
                                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 4)
                                }
                                .offset(x: 15)
                                Text(location.conditions)
                                    .font(.custom("SF Pro Display", size: 24))
                            }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -8, leading: 0, bottom: -8, trailing: 0))


                            VStack(spacing: -20) {
                                HourlyWeatherView(weatherVM: location)

                                DailyWeatherView(weatherVM: location)
                            }

                            Spacer()

                        }
                        .onAppear() {
                            if location.city != weatherVM.city {
                                weatherVM.city = location.city
                                currentPage += multiLocationVM.weatherVM.firstIndex(of: location)!
                                location.page = currentPage
                                
                                print("current \(currentPage)")
                                print("Location \(location.page)")
                            } else {
                                return
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(currentPage)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
                .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 70)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct LocationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LocationView(weatherVM: WeatherViewViewModel(city: "Phoenix"), multiLocationVM: MultiLocationViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a separated view for page(s) in TabView and then you'll see what's needed to be injected and what should be internal for each page view.

Comment: @Asperi sorry but I am not sure how this would help me identify each page. what do you mean when you said I will see what is needed to be injected and what should be internal for each page view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you don't need the currentPage counter as `TabView(selection: )`is handling that for you. The selection, in your case `pageSelection` will update when the user swipes, or you can set it programmatically. You just have to provide a fitting `.tag`:

```
//  dummy test data
struct Weather {
    var city: String
    var icon: String
    var temp: Int
    var condition: String
}

let multiLocationVM = [
    Weather(city: "Vancouver", icon: "cloud", temp: 64, condition: " Mostly Cloudy"),
    Weather(city: "New York", icon: "cloud.sun", temp: 78, condition: " Mostly Sunny"),
    Weather(city: "Los Angeles", icon: "sun.max", temp: 91, condition: " Sunny"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var pageSelection = "Vancouver" // default here
    @State var currentPage: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [Color(.yellow), Color(.blue)], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)).ignoresSafeArea()
            
            if multiLocationVM.count == 0 {
                // BlankLocationView(multiLocationVM: multiLocationVM)
            } else {
                TabView(selection: $pageSelection) {
                    ForEach(multiLocationVM, id: \.city) { location in
                        LocalWeather(location: location)
                            .tag(location.city) // set tab id here
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 70)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


struct LocalWeather: View {
    
    let location: Weather
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: -10) {
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image(systemName: location.icon)
                        .font(.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 32))
                        .offset(x: -90, y: -35)
                    
                    Text("\(location.temp)")
                        .font(.system(size: 96, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                        .tracking(-0.41)
                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 4)
                }
                .offset(x: 15)
                Text(location.condition)
                    .font(.custom("SF Pro Display", size: 24))
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -8, leading: 0, bottom: -8, trailing: 0))
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]